# Allow only Googlebot to index everything

Tags: seo, robots.txt, google-index

I want to disallow all bots to crawl and index a site. Except Googlebot. I want to allow google to index the index (/) URL, but nothing else. Preferably in robots.txt.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Comment: @JohnConde Aha. I see. Thanks for the information. I'll ask over there.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a robot.txt.

Just create one in your public folder of the website and add;

User-agent: Googlebot

Allow: /

User-agent: *

Disallow: /

This will allow google crawler to index all pages and disallow all other crawlers for the whole website.

For details refer: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en

I know this could be considered off topic, but still thought I'd answer if this helps.
As John Conde suggested, try webmasters....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've posted this at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ as well. Yes, robots.txt it is. However, your posted solution will block Googlebot from the entire site, right? I want to allow / (index) only for Googlebot.

Comment: Ah, I see...Hope you find a solution in webmasters. All the best

Comment: Updated the answer FYI